# Lorentz transformations, why $t$ and not $t'$?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

In the derivation of the Lorentz tranformation you get the fromuls:

$$x=k(x'-ut')$$
$$x'=k(x+ut)$$

where $k$ is a constant that is yet to be determied ($k= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}}$)  why is the formulas of the above like tis rather then the below:

$$x=k(x'-ut)$$
$$x'=k(x+ut')$$

(where all values with ' after them are from the same reference frame).

Comment: You must be able to transform into an unknown reference frame solely knowing the values in your reference frame. Your $x'$, on the contrary, depends on $t'$ - how can that be? How can the position of something (unmoving) in a frame depend on the time in that frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to express one reference frame in terms of the other. So for example if you have $x$ and $t$ you would like to figure out $x'$ and $t'$. Therefore it makes sense that $x'$ is expressed purely in terms of the unprimed reference frame ($x$ and $t$). The equations you suggested are not really useful because they imply you know both reference frames' coordinates, and hence you need no equations to extract the values of $(t',x')$ or $(t,x)$